# ideone wrong output c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Why is this giving wrong output?

http://ideone.com/0hCkRp

```
#define ul unsigned
namespace my_const{
    const ul decimal_accuracy_10 = pow(10, 2);//change rhs to 100 -> works fine
};
struct Vector2D{
    int x[2];
    Vector2D(float a, float b){
        x[0] = a*my_const::decimal_accuracy_10;
        x[1] = b*my_const::decimal_accuracy_10;
    }
    Vector2D(){}
    inline void print(){
        cout << "\n" << (float)x[0] / 100.0f << " " << x[1] / 100.0f << "\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    Vector2D my(0.01f, 0.02f), ball(0.03f, 0.04f);
    my.print();
}
```

while this one is correct?

http://ideone.com/kUrBTE

```
#define ul unsigned
namespace my_const{
    const ul decimal_accuracy_10 = 100;//change rhs to 100 -> works fine
};
```

just changing the 100 there makes it run perfectly. Why?

Comment: I get the correct output on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f60667a83f6981a3).

Comment: The reason may be because you are calling a function during initialization of a variable.  Essentially, you are declaring a variable that may be initialized before `main` and possibly before the C runtime library is initialized.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me – it seems that the compiler has inlined the result of `pow(10,2)` and forgotten about the conversion to integer. (You'll get the same results if you inline it by hand.)

Comment: Can't reproduce using your posted code with minor modifications: http://ideone.com/zZCtrz